# PHP namespaces - why do I have to "use {Parent}" if declaring Parent\Child?

Tags: php, namespaces

New to using namespaces in PHP and have hit something I don't quite understand.

**file:  common.php**

```
namespace Base;

function c_foo(){ return 0 };
```

**file: worker.php**

This does not work:

```
namespace Base\Worker;

Class worker {
    public function do_work(){ return  c_foo() ) };  <--unknown function "c_foo"
}
```

This works:

```
namespace Base\Worker;
use Base;

Class worker {
    public function do_work(){ return  Base\c_foo() ) };  
}
```

I find the need to preface function calls with `{namespace}\` to be kind of awkward.  What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to make the parent namespace functions available in a child namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've declared the namespace `Base\Worker` at the top of the file, so if you want to use something outside of that namespace you need to include its namespace along with its name.

You should be able to do:

```
namespace Base\Worker;
use function Base\c_foo; // php >= 5.6

c_foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't works because when you call `c_foo()` php will search for a function defined under the `Base\Worker` namespace. ( `Base\Worker\c_foo()` ). From php 5.6 you can just import the function.

```
use function Base\c_foo;
```